# Matrix Indexes that fulfill Condition

Tags: r

I have a matrix, that looks like this

```
myMatrix <- matrix(data = TRUE, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
myMatrix[as.matrix(expand.grid(1:2, 1:2))] <- FALSE

myMatrix

      [,1]  [,2] [,3]
[1,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
```

and I would like to get a dataframe or a matrix that lists all row and column indexes where `myMatrix` is `TRUE`:

```
  column row
1      3   1
2      3   2
3      1   3
4      2   3
5      3   3
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can either use `which`

```
which(myMatrix, arr.ind = TRUE)
```

Or with `arrayInd` and specify the `.dims`

Answer (score 1):

We could use `row` and `col` to get row and column index of each element in matrix and subset the `TRUE` values using logical values of `myMatrix`.

```
data.frame(column = col(myMatrix)[myMatrix], row = row(myMatrix)[myMatrix])
```